# Passing a variable of any type for a custom print-debugging implementation

Tags: c++, debugging

I am implementing a print debugging system for a school assignment. I apologize if the answer is obvious, I am still learning c++.

I want to create a function, that takes three parameters: an error, a variable name, and the variable itself, and logs such information somewhere that can be viewed later. It would work like this:

```
int bad_variable = 2;
debug_log("Variable unexpected value", "bad_variable", bad_variable);
```

The problem is, I would have no idea what type of variable to expect when parsing `bad_variable` to `debug_log`, and therefore it cannot be defined. To my knowledge there is no way to parse a variable of an unknown type... however the c++ standard library does just that in the function `std::to_string`!

`std::to_string` could be the answer to my problem, I could just pass my `bad_variable` into `std::to_string` to convert it to a string, having `debug_log` expect the output string. However, I would have to type `std::to_string` every time I called the log function.

```
debug_log("Variable unexpected value", "bad_variable", std::to_string(bad_variable));
```

This to me seems like a patchwork solution to something that must have a simpler answer. I want to keep this debug function as simplistic as possible. How could I create a function that takes an unknown variable type, and generates a string containing the value of that variable?

Comment: look up templates. but keep in mind that these are running at compile time .. not runtime

Comment: It seems that you want either *function overloading* or (more likely) *function templates*. You should be able to find information about these in your instruction material or other introductional book to C++. (though maybe in an advanced section)

Comment: @DanielJour You mean that the type at each call site is determined at compile-time. They are not evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: Function overloading is better solution, however templates seem to be the best solution. I will read more into templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I create a function that takes an unknown variable type, and generates a string containing the value of that variable?

Since you've tagged this question C++, one nice way of doing so is by using templates:

```
     template<typename t_value>
      string convToString(t_value value)  {
       std::ostringstream oss; 
       oss << value;  
       return oss.str();
     }
```

Comment: That's assuming that the type in question can be streamed to a stream. That is *not* universally true and certainly doesn't match OPs question of " Passing a variable of any type ..." (But that's probably impossible anyway).